# Tailwind CSS 'justify-center' doesn't center properly within another flex div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind CSS and trying to create a login page in which on large normal devices, a sidebar with a form will show (and an image or design will be put next to it), and on mobile devices, the sidebar will disappear and the form will show on the designs/image that was initially put next to the sidebar. But, for some reason it won't center items within the sidebar using 'justify-center' or anything else. In inspect element the class for 'justify-center' is greyed out as if it's not in use and a little info box says the following:
`This element is a flex item, i.e. a child of a flex container, but justify-content only applies to containers. Try setting the justify-content on the container element or use justify-self instead.`

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <title>Tailwind CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/out.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap min-h-screen">
    <div class="justify-center basis-1/3 bg-red-500 hidden lg:block">
      <div>login</div>
    </div>
    <div><div>login2 area (for mobile devices)</div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can only apply `justify` to a container element as the error states. Try this `  <div class="flex flex-wrap min-h-screen justify-center">` and remove `justify-center` from your child

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to `center` the content within the sidebar using `justify-center` but `justify-center` applies to `flex containers` not `flex items`. To center the content within the sidebar, you need to use `justify-center` on the parent container of the sidebar.

Here is how you can modify your code:

```
  <div class="flex flex-wrap min-h-screen">
    <div class="w-full lg:w-1/3 flex justify-center bg-red-500 hidden lg:block">
      <div>login</div>
    </div>
    <!--Login area2 here -->
  </div>
```

I executed the code and got this as output:

[On small devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UBNm.png)

[sidebar appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKm7z.png)

Happy coding and have a nice day.